# Extract from data frame instances of two people working together on a matter, plus hours and matter name

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

My eventual goal is to create a network graph, probably with `igraph`, that shows for a 100-person group who each person has worked with on various matters (projects).  The thickness of the edges between two person in the graph will reflect the hours the person worked on the matter and the graph will identify the name of the matter they both worked on.

So far, I have used `dplyr` to create a wide data frame that looks like the toy data set below.

```
dput(soQ) 

structure(list(Matter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Person1 = c(5,    
0, 0, 0, 2, 4), Person2 = c(0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0), Person3 = c(2,    
2, 0, 0, 3, 2), Person4 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)), row.names = c(NA,    
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Can someone show how R can create a data frame that lists instances of two people working on the same matter and for those instances include the matter name and hours?  The result might look like this:

```
Person   WorkedWith  Matter  Hours

Person1   Person3     A       5

Person1   Person3     E       2

Person1   Person3     F       4

Person1   Person4     F       4

Person3   Person1     A       2

Person3   Person1     E       3
```

etc

Person1 worked with Person2 on no matters, with Person3 on 3 matters (A, E and F), and with Person4 on one matter (F).  Person1 and Person3 recorded different numbers of hours on the matters they worked on together.

Person2 worked with Person3 on one matter (B) and with Person4 on one matter (B), and so forth.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```r
df <- structure(list(Matter = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), Person1 = c(5,    
0, 0, 0, 2, 4), Person2 = c(0, 3, 0, 2, 0, 0), Person3 = c(2,    
2, 0, 0, 3, 2), Person4 = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2)), row.names = c(NA,    
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Matter) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>%
  left_join(., ., by = "Matter") %>%
  filter(name.x != name.y) %>%
  transmute(Person = name.x, WorkedWith = name.y,
    Matter, Hours = value.x) %>%
  arrange(Person)
```

Comment: Excellent.  It took me much longer to struggle with code and eventually create the question than you took to answer it!   But you brought in techniques I just didn't know.  I ran the code against my actual data and got an error for the transmute() call:  "Error: Column 'Name' [what I call Matter] can't be modified because it's a grouping variable".  When I removed it, the column title remained 'Name' so all was well.

Comment: Glad it worked. I work with networks for my research so I've done very similar things before. If there is a change I can make to make the answer better, let me know.